# Angular js inline conditions - detect number

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Data come from db , and this html element is a ng-repeat

```
{{count}}
```

**My Question**

How can i show if else condition that,

If `count`  is `null` (nothing count value) I would show `0` (count value should be zero) , else show original `count` value

I hope there are solution like   `{{count if '' else ''}}`

Comment: You can simply use `{{count || 0}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have have logic in your view with `{{count || 0}}` or `{{ count ? count : 0 }}` but this makes maintainability more difficult and duplicates logic.

A better option would be to create a custom filter. This will allow you to define you condition in a single place and makes it re-usable in many directives but also testable.

```
.filter('isEmpty', function() {
   return function (data) {
    return (data === null || data === undefined) ? 0 : data;   
   }
});
```

And you would use it like

```
{{item | isEmpty}}
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fhfsex4v/2/

EDIT: Here's the docs for filter that will explain what its doing and also how to pass optional extra parameters into your filters and other cool stuff.
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Answer (score 2):

How about `{{ count ? count : 0 }}`